# Is it possible to have open-uri maintain the extension?

Tags: ruby, open-uri

In Ruby, when you open a remote file with open-uri, the file object ends up having a path with something like this: `/tmp/20120329-2113-1-0762/open-uri20120329-1-7dit2c`. I have some file processing that depends on the extension of the file being present. Is there a way to keep the extension or even force it, when using open-uri?

Here's a short interaction showing what happens when you open a remote file using open-uri and get the path of it. The path looks completely different to the remote URL since it's a temporary unique file that was generate for that object, but the issue is the lack of extension:

```
> require "open-uri"
 => true

> f = open("http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/sprites.png")
 => #<File:/var/folders/zq/vx2std7x5qj54xc1g4hpm14h0000gn/T/open-uri20120401-38087-13mm6zy>

> f.path
 => "/var/folders/zq/vx2std7x5qj54xc1g4hpm14h0000gn/T/open-uri20120401-38087-13mm6zy"
```

Comment: You need to show some code. Open-URI is the pipe and isn't responsible for saving the file, your code is.

Comment: @theTinMan open-uri downloads and *saves* the file, then it opens it for you to use it. That file has the wrong extension. I'll post some code to show that.

Comment: It's saving it as a temporary buffer, which isn't for you to use as the final file. `read` the file-handle you get back from `open` and save it where you want it.

Comment: @theTinMan I'm not trying to use the file in any other way than by trying to read it, but I wish the temporary buffer returned a path with the proper extension. I could just then use it instead of having to write it down, open it, use it, close it, delete.

Comment: That may be, however your use subverts the purpose of the temporary file. It's not there for your use, it's for the use of Open::URI. A lot of things create temporary files on a modern OS, but they are understood to be there for the sole use of the routine that created it. Trying to use the temporary file is not supported and you go there at your own risk because the location and/or file format could change with no warning.

Answer (score -1):

Why not just save it with the right extension to /tmp, and open it from there? It's an extra step, but you can look for a more efficient solution when it becomes a bottleneck.

Comment: It's what I'm doing, but it means that open-uri downloads the file, opens it, I read all its contents, and write it some other other file which then I open to perform operations with it. I don't like it, it's not elegant, it's a waste of resources and the source-code is really confusing.

Comment: I agree it's not elegant, but it doesn't have to be. It has to be practical. Just extract the hack into a method called download_by_keeping_extension_and_reopen and the code will not look so confusing. If you're worried about the resources, you can just re-implement what open-uri does: download with Curb or any http lib, save to file, and open the file.

Comment: +1 @Leventix: "Elegant" is never elegant when you get under the covers, because at some point it's going to be messy as can be. It's the syntactic sugar at the higher levels that allow us to believe things are elegant. Curb, Typhoeus and the other HTTP libs are going to buffer to disk too, rather than stream to memory only, because they are concerned about filling memory if a multi-GB file is being received. Using Net::HTTP it's possible to stream into memory by writing code to do so, but that is hardly scalable.

Comment: @theTinMan I don't mind buffering, I do mind doing it twice because the first time the extension is not respected. That is the inelegant part.